Need pull the Azure tags information(Name, values) which are updated under 105 subscriptions
However, I'm trying to pull the tag information(Name, Values) for a single subscription using PS, with the below script where the output looks like below(in link)
Script:
$subscriptionDetails = Get-AzSubscription
$tags = $subscriptionDetails.Tags
$tagData = $tags.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubscriptionId   = $subscriptionDetails.Id
        SubscriptionName = $subscriptionDetails.Name
        TagName          = $Name
        TagValue         = $Value
    }
}

$tagData | Export-Csv -Path "SubscriptionTags.csv" -NoTypeInformation`your text`

Output
(TagName&TagValue) not receiving
My target is to pull Azure tags information(Name&Values) which are updated for 105 subscriptions


to pull Azure tags information(Name&Values) which are updated for 105 subscriptions.

You can use the below script to get the list of Subscriptions with Tag Name and Tag value using PowerShell.
Script:
$subscriptionDetails = Get-AzSubscription

$tagData = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptionDetails) {
    $tags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)"
    foreach ($tagKey in $tags.Properties.TagsProperty.Keys) {
        $tagValue = $tags.Properties.TagsProperty[$tagKey]
        $tagData += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionId   = $subscription.Id
            SubscriptionName = $subscription.Name
            TagName          = $tagKey
            TagValue         = $tagValue
        }
    }
}

$tagData | Export-Csv -Path "SubscriptionTags.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Output:
SubscriptionId                       SubscriptionName           TagName   TagValue
--------------                       ----------------           -------   --------
bxxxxxxx-6b90-4f69-yyyy-e7c0zzzzzzzz Axxx xxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxxxxxx data      results 
bxxxxxxx-6b90-4f69-yyyy-e7c0zzzzzzzz Axxx xxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxxxxxx createdby venkat  


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Removed :) image from answer.
